# Is it possible to search for text within a File?

Tags: file-processing, file-storage

Let's say I am using Libraries and it contains a document that says something like:

```
John has an apple tree.  This tree is very old.  It gives off fruit.
```

And the user wanted to find all files with the text `apple tree`.  It would cause that record to be brought back.  Is there any way to filter like this?

Could it be done using either Libraries, Content, or Knowledge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Salesforce help document for Libraries, Content and Files, yes.

> If your administrator enables document content search, Salesforce also performs a full-text search of the document. When a new document is uploaded or an old one is replaced, its contents are available for searches.

The help document notes which file types are able to be processed by the indexer for content searching.

Files:
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_searching.htm&language=en_US

Libraries:
http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=docs_search.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks, I had been reading this and test this just before I noticed your answer.